# Downloading Fashion MNIST file in TensorFlow tutorial is taking forever

Tags: tensorflow, mnist

I am trying to do this tutorial for a machine learning class I am taking in college.

> www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification

When it executes the lines

```
 fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

 (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

it is taking forever to download the data.  At the rate it is downloading, it is going to take a few days or weeks to download all of it.  I am using a MacBook.  My classmate is also using a MacBook and when he downloads the data it only takes a few seconds.  Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the download was giving me an error. By digging into the error I was able to find the file in which the base URL was declared, which in my case was:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/datasets/fashion_mnist.py
```

At line 44 I have commented out the line:

```
# base = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/'
```

And declared a different base URL, which I had found looking into the [documentation](https://github.com/zalandoresearch/fashion-mnist#get-the-data) of the original dataset:

```
base = 'http://fashion-mnist.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/'
```

The download started immediately and gave no errors. Hope this helps.